# How to upload several files with multer in Express/NodeJs

Tags: multer

I am prototying a system I want to send multiple files at once. My multer versions 1.4.5

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" action="/anunciar" >

<input type="text" >

 <input type="file" name="photo1">
 <input  type="file" name="photo2">
 <input type="file" name="photo3">

</form>
```

My failed attempt

```
router.post('/anunciar', campos.fields([{name: 'foto1'}]),  async function(req, res, next) {

     

    console.log(req.files.foto2.buffer);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough it is req.files.foto1[0].buffer